# DocuSign Agent/Specify Recipient role

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign's RESTful APIs to create and send envelopes for our clients for last few years with .net framework. We have encountered a strange issue using the Approve tab with a few of our clients' accounts. For some clients' accounts, we are able to add the Approve tab fine while we are receiving an exception while adding the Approve tab for other client accounts. Here is how we are adding the Approve tab from our codebase.

```
If signer.Tabs.ApproveTabs Is Nothing Then
                                signer.Tabs.ApproveTabs = New List(Of DocuSign.eSign.Model.Approve)
                            End If
                            Try
                                Dim approvatab As New DocuSign.eSign.Model.Approve

                                If Not currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent Is Nothing Then
                                    approvatab.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent
                                End If
                                approvatab.AnchorString = currtab.anchorString
                                approvatab.AnchorUnits = currtab.anchorUnits
                                approvatab.AnchorXOffset = currtab.anchorXOffset
                                approvatab.AnchorYOffset = currtab.anchorYOffset

                                If Not currtab.bold Is Nothing Then
                                    approvatab.Bold = currtab.bold
                                End If
                                approvatab.ButtonText = currtab.buttonText
                                approvatab.ConditionalParentLabel = currtab.conditionalParentLabel
                                approvatab.ConditionalParentValue = currtab.conditionalParentValue
                                approvatab.Font = currtab.font
                                approvatab.FontColor = currtab.fontColor
                                approvatab.FontSize = currtab.fontSize
                                approvatab.Height = currtab.height
                                If Not currtab.italic Is Nothing Then
                                    approvatab.Italic = currtab.italic
                                End If
                                approvatab.PageNumber = currtab.pageNumber
                                approvatab.RecipientId = currtab.recipientId
                                approvatab.TabId = currtab.tabId
                                approvatab.TabLabel = currtab.tabLabel
                                approvatab.TabOrder = currtab.tabOrder
                                If Not currtab.underline Then
                                    approvatab.Underline = currtab.underline
                                End If

                                approvatab.Width = currtab.width
                                approvatab.XPosition = currtab.xPosition
                                approvatab.YPosition = currtab.yPosition
                                approvatab.DocumentId = currtab.documentId
                                signer.Tabs.ApproveTabs.Add(approvatab)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Dim errmsg As String = ex.Message.ToString
                            End Try
```

The exception that we are getting while adding the Approve tab is
"Conversion from string "false" to type 'Long' is not valid"

The same code works fine for some of our clients' accounts and we are able to add the Approve tab fine.

Please advise,

Minal

Comment: 1. Is this consistent for certain customers? I wonder if it's a bad error message but the real issue is these customers' account plan does not include this feature.
2. Can you get us API logs/accountIDs that are bad. Anything to try to look this up

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The decline tab is working fine for the same client so I believe that this feature is included in their account plan. I will try to get API logs from their account.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some recommendations:

1. Consider using the [eSign Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.Click). It works for VB code as well as C# code. Since it's generated from the swagger file of the [DocuSign eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/support) it is always consistent with the latest API.
2. Make sure to use the [v2.1 version](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/esignature-rest-api-v20-entering-maintenance-mode) of the eSign API and not version 2.0

Note that sometimes the API expect "false" and other times false for a Boolean value (meaning it's a string in some cases whereas it's a Boolean in the JSON in others). It's possible that there are temporary differences between customers' accounts configurations, but in the long term if you use the latest eSign API - they should behave the same.

Lastly, it could be a case of a misleading error message which hides the real issue with the account. If the issue persists I would advise to contact customer support with account numbers to try to find out.